# I get fatalExceptionError while uploading file, but file still uploads fine

Tags: java, android

I am uploading image and also sending some parameters with it. I am getting errors in my logcat while doing so.

Here is my code

```
public class Camera extends Activity {
ImageView ivUserImage;
Button bUpload;
Intent i;
int CameraResult = 0;
Bitmap bmp;
public String globalUID;
UserFunctions userFunctions;
String photoName;
InputStream is;

int serverResponseCode = 0;
ProgressDialog dialog = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.camera);

    userFunctions = new UserFunctions();
    globalUID = getIntent().getExtras().getString("globalUID");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), globalUID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    ivUserImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivUserImage);
    bUpload = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bUpload);
    openCamera();
}

private void openCamera() {
    i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(i, CameraResult);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        //set image taken from camera on ImageView
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        ivUserImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);

        //Create new Cursor to obtain the file Path for the large image
         String[] largeFileProjection = {
                 MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
                 MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA
         };

         String largeFileSort = MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID + " DESC";
         //final String photoName = MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME;
         Cursor myCursor = this.managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, largeFileProjection, null, null, largeFileSort);

         try {
             myCursor.moveToFirst();
             //This will actually give you the file path location of the image.
             final String largeImagePath = myCursor.getString(myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA));
             //final String photoName = myCursor.getString(myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME));
             //Log.e("URI", largeImagePath);

             File f = new File("" + largeImagePath);

             photoName = f.getName();

             bUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Camera.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);
                         new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        public void run() {
                                            //tv.setText("uploading started.....");
                                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File is uploading...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }
                                     });
                                 if(imageUpload(globalUID, largeImagePath)) {
                                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                 } else {
                                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error uploading image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                 }
                                 //Log.e("Response: ", response);
                                 //System.out.println("RES : " + response);
                                }
                              }).start();
                        }
                });
         } finally {
             myCursor.close();
         }
         //Uri uriLargeImage = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(imageId));
         //String imageUrl = getRealPathFromURI(uriLargeImage);
    }
}

public boolean imageUpload(String uid, String imagepath) {
    boolean success = false;
    //Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);

    byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();
    String ba1=Base64.encodeToString(ba, 0);

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",ba1));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uid", uid));

    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.example.info/androidfileupload/index.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if(response != null) {
            success = true;
        }
        is = entity.getContent();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }
    dialog.dismiss();
    return success;
}
```

Here is my logcat

```
06-23 11:54:48.555: E/AndroidRuntime(30601): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-11
06-23 11:54:48.555: E/AndroidRuntime(30601): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
06-23 11:54:48.555: E/AndroidRuntime(30601):    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:513)
06-23 11:54:48.555: E/AndroidRuntime(30601):    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.toString(AbstractStringBuilder.java:650)
06-23 11:54:48.555: E/AndroidRuntime(30601):    at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:664)
06-23 11:54:48.555: E/AndroidRuntime(30601):    at org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils.format(URLEncodedUtils.java:170)
06-23 11:54:48.555: E/AndroidRuntime(30601):    at org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity.<init>(UrlEncodedFormEntity.java:71)
06-23 11:54:48.555: E/AndroidRuntime(30601):    at com.zafar.login.Camera.imageUpload(Camera.java:155)
06-23 11:54:48.555: E/AndroidRuntime(30601):    at com.zafar.login.Camera$1$1.run(Camera.java:119)
06-23 11:54:48.555: E/AndroidRuntime(30601):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
06-23 11:54:53.960: E/WindowManager(30601): Activity com.zafar.login.DashboardActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@405db540 that was originally added here
06-23 11:54:53.960: E/WindowManager(30601): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.zafar.login.DashboardActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@405db540 that was originally added here
06-23 11:54:53.960: E/WindowManager(30601):     at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:266)
06-23 11:54:53.960: E/WindowManager(30601):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:174)
06-23 11:54:53.960: E/WindowManager(30601):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:117)
06-23 11:54:53.960: E/WindowManager(30601):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
06-23 11:54:53.960: E/WindowManager(30601):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
06-23 11:54:53.960: E/WindowManager(30601):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:107)
06-23 11:54:53.960: E/WindowManager(30601):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:90)
06-23 11:54:53.960: E/WindowManager(30601):     at com.zafar.login.Camera$1.onClick(Camera.java:110)
06-23 11:54:53.960: E/WindowManager(30601):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
06-23 11:54:53.960: E/WindowManager(30601):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
06-23 11:54:53.960: E/WindowManager(30601):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-23 11:54:53.960: E/WindowManager(30601):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-23 11:54:53.960: E/WindowManager(30601):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-23 11:54:53.960: E/WindowManager(30601):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
06-23 11:54:53.960: E/WindowManager(30601):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-23 11:54:53.960: E/WindowManager(30601):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-23 11:54:53.960: E/WindowManager(30601):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
06-23 11:54:53.960: E/WindowManager(30601):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
06-23 11:54:53.960: E/WindowManager(30601):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-23 11:54:55.190: I/Process(30601): Sending signal. PID: 30601 SIG: 9
```

Comment: OutOfMemory, may be your image is too large

Comment: But it does upload image to the server after that I get these errors

Comment: that part you haven't mentioned in the question, as per your question title, it stats that error occurs while uploading the image, not after the image is uploaded

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

After adding `try and catch` inside thread it works. Here is where I added try catch

```
public void run() {
       try {
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File is uploading...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if(imageUpload(globalUID, largeImagePath)) {
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error uploading image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

}
```